# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined afterViewInit in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ace-editor

Hello Im working on an Angular project and I have my component which is used to edit code on AceEditor, like this :

```
  public lesson!: LessonId;
  cssResponse = '';
  aceEditor: any = '';
  idLesson = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('lessonsName');
  constructor(
    private aceEditorService: AceEditorService,
    private lessonsService: LessonsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.getLessons();
  }
  getLessons() {
    this.lessonsService.Lesson(this.idLesson).subscribe((lesson: LessonId) => {
      this.lesson = lesson;
      console.log(this.lesson);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ace.config.set('fontSize', '16px');
    ace.config.set(
      'basePath',
      'https://unpkg.com/ace-builds@1.4.12/src-noconflict'
    );

    this.aceEditor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);
    this.aceEditor.setTheme('ace/theme/dracula');
    this.aceEditor.session.setMode('ace/mode/css');
    this.aceEditor.on('change', () => {
      this.cssResponse = this.aceEditor.getValue();
      this.aceEditorService.setCssValues(this.cssResponse);
    });
    this.aceEditor.session.setValue(this.lesson.cssArea);
    this.aceEditor.setOptions({
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
      enableSnippets: true,
      enableLiveAutocompletion: false,
      useSoftTabs: true,
      tabSize: 1,
      cursorStyle: 'smooth',
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
```

And my LessonId interface like :

```
export interface LessonId {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  htmlArea: string;
  cssArea: string;
}
```

I've got this error when I want to display the 'CssArea'

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cssArea')
at IdeCssExerciceComponent.ngAfterViewInit (ide-css-exercice.component.ts:48:49)
at callHook (core.mjs:2551:1)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2520:1)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2471:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9566:1)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10692:1)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9291:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9545:1)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10692:1)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9291:1)
```

I don't know why it it's undefind I tried multiple things and I don't understand why the properties of my services isn't in my interface
Anyone can help me ? please

Comment: Just as a helpful unrelated tip when you are setting up your properties for your theme you have hardcoded params.  You should set them dynamically from your config file you can use a web config or your default appsettings json to store these values.  It's always best to try to stay away from hardcoding.   The benefit of changing these from the appsettings is not having to rebuild the whole project and redeploy if you need to change the values. if they never change at least make a separate config obj   like ConfigurationManager.ts  export const ConfigurationManager = {  test: "im a value" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up a race condition: If `this.getLessons();` doesn't complete before `ngAfterViewInit()`, `this.lesson` will be undefined. Move `this.aceEditor.session.setValue(this.lesson.cssArea);` to inside of the `getLessons()` and `getLessons()` to after `this.aceEditor = ace.edit(this.editor.nativeElement);`.

Comment: Damn that's right ! Thanks Dude